# user control with images not showing images

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm writing with wpf
I have a dll with user control and images inside the user control
i added the user control to a project but the images are not shown (the user control are shown but without any images)

here's the code for the user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Shkila.About.About"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Background="RoyalBlue">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
        <Image Source="Resources/ShkilaLogo.png"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="1" Foreground="Yellow" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="2" Foreground="Yellow"  Margin="5"/>                
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock> 
            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http:\\www.vbcity.com" TextDecorations="None"> 
                <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/About;Component/Resources/ShkilaLogo.png"></Image> 
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I want to display the user control with the images, How it can be done
Thank you all.

Comment: Make sure the image file's Build Action is set to Resource, and use a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx): `pack://application:,,,/About;component/Resources/ShkilaLogo.png`, where `About` is actually a valid assembly name.

Comment: you right i didn't set the build action to resource and i needed to use application not siteoforigin thank you